# jquery mobile change icon project android cordova

Tags: android, html, cordova, icons

Hy
I Can not Change the ' icon of the project Cordova . You can tell me what to ADD in the xml file ? and I have to change all the icons in the / res / drawable ?
All the program is the last version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know you will find the icons in the `res` folder

Below are the folders that each has an icon for different sized screens. You need to keep the same name (ic_launcher) and the same size so simply replace the icon with your App icon in each folder.

That's all you need to do unless cordova works differently

[image]